# Dynamic-height cell in collection view

Tags: ios, swift

**I want to resize cells like this app:**

[image]

**As you can see, right cells are shorter than left. To achive same thing i used following code:**

```
var testI=1
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                           sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var cellHeight=287
    if testI % 2 == 0 {
        cellHeight=247
    }
    testI += 1
    return CGSizeMake(CGFloat(176), CGFloat(cellHeight))
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**I dont want these top spaces. How can I remove them?
My collection view attrs:**

[image]

**How can I achive that?**

Comment: Take a look in this repository in deep https://github.com/demonnico/PinterestSwift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/) expects cells in question to have the same height *(or width depending on scroll direction)* so that it can correctly align them horizontally or vertically.

Thus, you can't use that to get the above effect. You need to create your own layout class which will have similar properties as `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` such as `minimumInteritemSpacing`, `sectionInset` etc. Besides, the new subclass *(which I will name  `UserCollectionViewLayout` from now on)* will be capable of generating all the layout attributes for each corresponding cell with a frame value having different height so that cells will be positioned just like in the image you've shared.

Before we begin, you should at least have a basic understanding about how to create custom layouts so I strongly recommend you to read [this article](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/) for a fresh start.

First, we need to create our own `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` class so we can store the **height** of the cell there for later use.

```
class UserCollectionViewLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
  var height: CGFloat = 0.0
}
```

Layout classes sometimes copy `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` when needed, so we need to override several methods to be able to pass `height` to copied object when it happens:

```
override func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
  let copy = super.copyWithZone(zone) as! UserCollectionViewLayoutAttributes
  copy.height = height
  return copy
}

override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
  if let object = object as? UserCollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    if height != object.height {
      return false
    }
    return super.isEqual(object)
  }
  return false
}
```

We are going to need a new protocol which will ask for delegate the height of each cell:

*(Similar to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.sizeForItemAtIndexPath`)*

```
protocol UserCollectionViewLayoutDelegate: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UserCollectionViewLayout, heightForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
}
```

OK, everything we need on our way to defining the layout is there. So, let's start:

```
class UserCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
  private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
  private var allAttributes = [UserCollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

  weak var delegate: UserCollectionViewLayoutDelegate!

  var numberOfColumns: Int = 2

  private var numberOfItems: Int {
    return collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0) ?? 0
  }

  private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    return CGRectGetWidth(collectionView?.bounds ?? CGRectZero)
  }

  private var itemWidth: CGFloat {
    return round(contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns))
  }
  ...
```

OK, let's explain the above properties piece by piece:

- `contentHeight`: Content height of collection view so it will know how to/where to scroll. Same as defining `scrollView.contentSize.height`.
- `allAttributes`: An array holding the attributes of each cell. It will be populated in [`prepareLayout()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617752-prepare) method.
- `numberOfColumns`: A value indicating how many cells will be shown at each row. It will be `2` in your example as you want to show 2 photos in a row.

Let's continue with overriding some important methods:

```
override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
  return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}

override class func layoutAttributesClass() -> AnyClass {
  return UserCollectionViewLayoutAttributes.self
}
```

The crucial part is to implement `prepareLayout` correctly. In this method, we are going to populate all the layout attributes corresponding to each indexPath, and store them in `allAttributes` for later use.

The layout looks like a 2D matrix of cells. However, height of each cell might be different. Thus, you should keep in mind that `frame.origin.y` value might not be same for cells positioned in the same row:

```
override func prepareLayout() {
  if allAttributes.isEmpty {
    let xOffsets = (0..<numberOfColumns).map { index -> CGFloat in
      return CGFloat(index) * itemWidth
    }
    var yOffsets = Array(count: numberOfColumns, repeatedValue: CGFloat(0))
    var column = 0

    for item in 0..<numberOfItems {
      let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
      let attributes = UserCollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)

      let cellHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, layout: self, heightForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)

      let frame = CGRect(x: xOffsets[column], y: yOffsets[column], width: itemWidth, height: cellHeight)

      attributes.frame = frame
      attributes.height = cellHeight

      allAttributes.append(attributes)

      yOffsets[column] = yOffsets[column] + cellHeight

      column = (column >= numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : column + 1
      contentHeight = max(contentHeight, CGRectGetMaxY(frame))
    }
  }
}

override func invalidateLayout() {
  allAttributes.removeAll()
  contentHeight = 0
  super.invalidateLayout()
}
```

We need to implement 2 more methods to let the layout know which layout attribute it should use upon displaying a cell which are:

- [`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelements)
- [`layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617797-layoutattributesforitem)

Let's give it a shot:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
  return cachedAttributes.filter { attribute -> Bool in
    return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, attribute.frame)
  }
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
  return cachedAttributes.filter { attribute -> Bool in
    return attribute.indexPath == indexPath
  }.first
}
```

OK, that's all for the layout part. Right now, we have a layout class capable of displaying cells with different height values in a single row. Now, we need to figure out how to pass `height` value to actual cell object.

Luckily for us, it is really straightforward if you are organizing your cell content using `AutoLayout`. There is a method named [`applyLayoutAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620139-apply) in `UICollectionViewCell` which enables you to make last minute changes on cell's layout.

```
class UserCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  let userView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
  private var heightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  override func applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    super.applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes)
    let attributes = layoutAttributes as! UserCollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    heightLayoutConstraint.constant = attributes.height
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    contentView.addSubview(userView)
    userView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
      "H:|[userView]|",
      options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY,
      metrics: nil,
      views: ["userView": userView])
    )

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
      "V:|[userView]|",
      options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX,
      metrics: nil,
      views: ["userView": userView])
    )

    heightLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
      item: self, 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 
      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
      toItem: nil, 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, 
      multiplier: 0.0, 
      constant: 0.0
    )
    heightLayoutConstraint.priority = 500
    contentView.addConstraint(heightLayoutConstraint)
  }
}
```

Getting all of them together, here is the result:

[image]

I am sure you can add `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `sectionInset` properties just like in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class in order to add some padding between cells.

*(Hint: you should tweak cell's frame in `prepareLayout` method accordingly.)*

You can download the example project from [here](https://github.com/ozgur/DynamicHeightCells).